# Why is my zpool mirrored?

Tags: raid, zfs

I can't figure out what im doing wrong according to the documentation

```
zpool create steam sdb1 sdc1
```

should make a striped pool over both those disks. However the total size availbe is the size of one disk?
What am I doing wrong?

```
 zpool status

 pool: steam
  state: ONLINE
   scan: none requested
 config:

         NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
         steam       ONLINE       0     0     0
           sdb1      ONLINE       0     0     0
           sdc1      ONLINE       0     0     0

  zfs list -o space
NAME   AVAIL   USED  USEDSNAP  USEDDS  USEDREFRESERV  USEDCHILD

steam  3.84T   240K         0     96K              0       144K
```

Comment: Can you please include `zpool stats` output? Thanks

Comment: Put in original comment for clarity

Comment: Thanks, that's striped, not mirrored; if it were mirrored you'd have `mirror-0` entry with the individual drives listed underneath it. How about `zfs list -o space`?

Comment: added to original, I was under the impression that striped striped the data across both disks.